# Is there an R function for checking if a specified GeoJSON object(polygon or multi-polygon) contains the specified point?

Tags: r, json, geojson, data-cleaning

I have an array of point

```
{
  "Sheet1": [
    {
      "CoM ID": "1040614",
      "Genus": "Washingtonia",
      "Year Planted": "1998",
      "Latitude": "-37.81387927",
      "Longitude": "144.9817733"
    },
    {
      "CoM ID": "1663526",
      "Genus": "Banksia",
      "Year Planted": "2017",
      "Latitude": "-37.79582801",
      "Longitude": "144.9160598"
    },
    {
      "CoM ID": "1031170",
      "Genus": "Melaleuca",
      "Year Planted": "1997",
      "Latitude": "-37.82326441",
      "Longitude": "144.9305296"
    }
  ]
}
```

and also an array of Geojson polygon in the same form as shown below:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","id":"01","properties":{"name":"Alabama","density":94.65},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-87.359296,35.00118],[-85.606675,34.984749],[-85.431413,34.124869],[-85.184951,32.859696],[-85.069935,32.580372],[-84.960397,32.421541],[-85.004212,32.322956],[-84.889196,32.262709],[-85.058981,32.13674],[-85.053504,32.01077],[-85.141136,31.840985],[-85.042551,31.539753],[-85.113751,31.27686],[-85.004212,31.003013],[-85.497137,30.997536],[-87.600282,30.997536],[-87.633143,30.86609],[-87.408589,30.674397],[-87.446927,30.510088],[-87.37025,30.427934],[-87.518128,30.280057],[-87.655051,30.247195],[-87.90699,30.411504],[-87.934375,30.657966],[-88.011052,30.685351],[-88.10416,30.499135],[-88.137022,30.318396],[-88.394438,30.367688],[-88.471115,31.895754],[-88.241084,33.796253],[-88.098683,34.891641],[-88.202745,34.995703],[-87.359296,35.00118]]]}}
```

I'm trying to find the Geojson polygons with points inside it using R.
For example how can I know if the three points I added above are inside the polygon?

The function I found may be helpful is the [point.in.polygon function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sp/versions/1.3-1/topics/point.in.polygon). but it doesn't support the Geojson format.

Is there any R function or any way would be useful to solve this problem?
It will be really helpful if it's return is the ID of the polygon.

Comment: Can you use `jsonlite` to parse those structs, extract the coordinates, and then call `point.in.polygon`? BTW: your title is *"if a polygon contains a point"*, but your last sentence is *"return is the ID"* ... does this mean you have multiple polygons to test against?

Comment: Thanks for your help, and Yes, it is what I mean here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use lawn pkg, e.g.,

```
x <- '{
"Sheet1": [
  {
    "CoM ID": "1040614",
    "Genus": "Washingtonia",
    "Year Planted": "1998",
    "Latitude": "-37.81387927",
    "Longitude": "144.9817733"
  },
  {
    "CoM ID": "1663526",
    "Genus": "Banksia",
    "Year Planted": "2017",
    "Latitude": "-37.79582801",
    "Longitude": "144.9160598"
  },
  {
    "CoM ID": "1031170",
    "Genus": "Melaleuca",
    "Year Planted": "1997",
    "Latitude": "-37.82326441",
    "Longitude": "144.9305296"
  }
]
}'

feature1 <- '{"type":"Feature","id":"01","properties":{"name":"Alabama","density":94.65},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-87.359296,35.00118],[-85.606675,34.984749],[-85.431413,34.124869],[-85.184951,32.859696],[-85.069935,32.580372],[-84.960397,32.421541],[-85.004212,32.322956],[-84.889196,32.262709],[-85.058981,32.13674],[-85.053504,32.01077],[-85.141136,31.840985],[-85.042551,31.539753],[-85.113751,31.27686],[-85.004212,31.003013],[-85.497137,30.997536],[-87.600282,30.997536],[-87.633143,30.86609],[-87.408589,30.674397],[-87.446927,30.510088],[-87.37025,30.427934],[-87.518128,30.280057],[-87.655051,30.247195],[-87.90699,30.411504],[-87.934375,30.657966],[-88.011052,30.685351],[-88.10416,30.499135],[-88.137022,30.318396],[-88.394438,30.367688],[-88.471115,31.895754],[-88.241084,33.796253],[-88.098683,34.891641],[-88.202745,34.995703],[-87.359296,35.00118]]]}}'
```

Do one test:

```
lawn_boolean_contains(as.feature(feature1), lawn_point('[144.9817733,-37.81387927]'))
#> FALSE
```

All at once:

```
apply(jsonlite::fromJSON(x)$Sheet1, 1, function(z) {
  lawn_boolean_contains(
    as.feature(feature1), 
    lawn_point(sprintf("[%s,%s]", z['Longitude'], z['Latitude']))
)
})
#>     1     2     3
#> FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful!